# Assigning value to an R object without using its name with get()

Tags: r

I am having a problem with `get()` in R.

I have a set of `data.frame`s with a common structure in my environment. I want to loop through these data frames and change the name of the 2nd column so that the name of the 2nd column contains a prefix from the 1st column.

For example, if column 1 = `A_cat` and column 2 is `dog`, I want column 2 to be changed to `A_dog`.

Below is an example of the R code I am using:

```
df <- data.frame('A_cat'= 1:10 , 'dog' = 11:20)

for( element in grep('^df$', names(environment()), value=TRUE) ) {

colnames(get(element))[2] <- paste(strsplit(colnames(get(element)) [1], '`_`')[[1]][1],
                               colnames(get(element))[2], sep='`_`')

}
```

The arguments within the for loop, on either side of the assignment operator, both give the expected result if I run them separately but when run together produce the following error.

> Error in colnames(get(element))[2] <- paste(strsplit(colnames(get(element))[1], :
>     could not find function "get<-"

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I have a set of dataframes with a common structure in my environment." Why aren't they nicely together in a list? Then you wouldn't need `get` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here would be one way to accomplish this goal if the data.frames have systematic names (here, df1 df2 df3, etc) and the prefix ends with "_" as in the example:

```
# suggested by @roland roll them up in a list:
myDfList <- mget(ls(pattern="^df"))

# change names
for(dfName in names(myDfList)) {
  names(myDfList[[dfName]])[2] <- paste0(gsub("^(.*_)", "\\1", 
                                           names(myDfList[[dfName]])[1]), 
                                    names(myDfList[[dfName]])[2])
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This does the same thing as the code in the question without using `get`:

```
df <- data.frame('A_cat'= 1:10 , 'dog' = 11:20)

e <- environment() ##
df.names <- grep("^df$", names(e), value = TRUE)

# nm is the current data frame name and nms are its column names
for(nm in df.names) {
  nms <- names(e[[nm]])
  names(e[[nm]])[2] <- paste0(sub("_.*", "_", nms[1]), nms[2])
}
```

giving:

```
> df
   A_cat A_dog
1      1    11
2      2    12
3      3    13
4      4    14
5      5    15
6      6    16
7      7    17
8      8    18
9      9    19
10    10    20
```

Keeping the data.frames in a named list as suggested in a comment to the question might be even better.  For example, if instead of keeping the data.frames in an environment they were in a list called e

```
e <- list(df = df)
```

then omit the line marked ## and the rest works as is.